# Python Machine Learning: Measuring confidence in individual classifications

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, astronomy

I am pretty new to machine learning. I am currently using sci-kit learn's DecisionTreeClassifier and RandomForestClassifier to look at astronomical data. It takes in a number of parameters and tries to classify the source as a supernova remnant, x-ray binary, or active galactic nuclei.

Unfortunately, I still have a statistically small sample size and I want to get a measure of how confident the model is in classifying unknown sources.

For example, say the algorithm predicts that a source is an x-ray binary. I want a measure of how likely that prediction is to being correct, or how confident the algorithm is in that prediction.

Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?